# Lodash _.map to get properties of an array of objects

Tags: typescript, lodash

I have an array of objects like so :

```
    users: [
        { name: 'missing!', ids: ['Not Specified']},
        { name: 'user1', ids: ['C.001', 'C.002', 'C.001.001']},
        { name: 'user2', ids: ['C.001', 'C.002', 'C.004', 'C.001.001']},
        { name: 'user3', ids: ['C.001', 'C.002', 'C.004', 'C.001.001']},
        { name: 'user4', ids: ['C.001', 'C.002', 'C.004', 'C.001.001']}
      ]
```

And what I want to achieve is getting an array of user names that have a certain id thats passed down.

For example if I pass an id of : 'C.001.001' , ['user1','user2','user3','user4'] should be returned.

If I pass 'C.123214123', ['missing!'] should be returned.

What I've tried and didn't work:

```
getUserNamesById(id: string) string[] {
   return _.map(this.users, user => {
         return _.find(user.ids,{id});
});}
```

This doesn't work and also doesn't treat the case where you don't find an Id and it returns ['missing'](and it also doesn't return the name property for that matter).

I am new to _.lodash and I want to learn it ,but I researched for nearly 2 hours and didn't get anywhere.

How do I achieve my output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the "missing" case separately.

You need to filter the list to get what matches
if any matches, map to get the name
else get the "missing" record

```js
const users = [
    { name: 'missing!', ids: ['Not Specified']},
    { name: 'user1', ids: ['C.001', 'C.002', 'C.001.001']},
    { name: 'user2', ids: ['C.001', 'C.002', 'C.004', 'C.001.001']},
    { name: 'user3', ids: ['C.001', 'C.002', 'C.004', 'C.001.001']},
    { name: 'user4', ids: ['C.001', 'C.002', 'C.004', 'C.001.001']}
];
      
function find(u, search) {
  const found = _.filter(u, (x) => _.some(x.ids, (id) => id === search));
  if (_.isEmpty(found)) {
    return ['missing!'];
  } else {
    return _.map(found, (f) => f.name);
  }
}
      
console.log(find(users, 'C.001.001'));
console.log(find(users, 'C.123.456'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.filtered()` with `Array.includes()` (or lodash equivalents) to filter the array, and then `Array.map()` to get the list of names:

```js
const filterById = (id, arr) => {
  const filtered = arr.filter(({ ids }) => ids.includes(id))
    .map(({ name }) => name);
  
  return filtered.length ? filtered : ['missing'];
}

const users = [{"name":"missing!","ids":["Not Specified"]},{"name":"user1","ids":["C.001","C.002","C.001.001"]},{"name":"user2","ids":["C.001","C.002","C.004","C.001.001"]},{"name":"user3","ids":["C.001","C.002","C.004","C.001.001"]},{"name":"user4","ids":["C.001","C.002","C.004","C.001.001"]}]
      
console.log(filterById('C.001.001', users));
console.log(filterById('132133333', users));
```

And the same idea with [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide):

```js
const { flow, filter, get, includes, map, cond, isEmpty, constant, stubtrue, identity } = _

const filterById = id => flow(
  filter(flow(get('ids'), includes(id))),
  cond([
    [isEmpty, constant(['missing'])],
    [stubtrue, map('name')]
  ])
)

const users = [{"name":"missing!","ids":["Not Specified"]},{"name":"user1","ids":["C.001","C.002","C.001.001"]},{"name":"user2","ids":["C.001","C.002","C.004","C.001.001"]},{"name":"user3","ids":["C.001","C.002","C.004","C.001.001"]},{"name":"user4","ids":["C.001","C.002","C.004","C.001.001"]}]
      
console.log(filterById('C.001.001')(users));
console.log(filterById('132133333')(users));
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comment: I used @crashmstr 's response and combined it with your usage of elvis operator as it seems to be the "cleaner" approach. thanks a lot :)